# jasperreporter view in springmvc format miss error

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports

Hello guys I use jasperreporter as a report lib ,use spring mvc as a controller 
,i put the two togeter with this

```
@Bean
 JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
  JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/jasperreports/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
  resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
  resolver.setViewNames("rpt_*");
  resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
  resolver.setOrder(0);
  return resolver;
}  

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  resolver.setOrder(1);
  return resolver;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "helloReport4", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRpt4(ModelMap modelMap, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
  modelMap.put("datasource", getWidgets());
  modelMap.put("format", "pdf");
  modelAndView = new ModelAndView("rpt_HelloWorld", modelMap);
  return modelAndView;
}
```

the above is config and controller
then i put compiled xxxx.jasper to somewhere of webapp directory 
but while the tomcat run the few hours ,about ten or more, when request the jasper view by browser ,it makes error like [ ***java.io.FileNotFoundException :can't load resource of xxxx.html.jasper***],and in my path ,put some xxxx.jasper
files ,but i have set the reporter format to **pdf** only ,can someone tell me about it!~